# iPhone style password control in Android with box for each dot

Tags: android

I am designing an "Enter Password" screen and wanted to make it in iPhone style with square box for each dot in the password. Is there any way in which I can get it as single control instead of having an Edittext for each dot(Hard way of doing it!!). Please help!! Thanks

[image]

Comment: a screenshot of what you are trying to implement would be useful for non iOS devs.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot clearer now. I can't help you though, I have never tried to do something like this. I don't think that Android has a native solution for this issue.
The system pincode screen does not implement this. Not sure if it is a good or a bad thing : the length of a password is a sensitive information.
If there is nothing similar on Github, your only solution is to implement it yourself. It doesn't seem especially difficult though.

Comment: Thanks @Teovald for the reply. I agree with you and in fact I am looking for a better work around than mine which is hiding the actual password Edittext and playing with visibility of 4 views with dot images on user input.

Comment: @Sree, Did u find solution to do this, if yes can you share that.

Comment: @Madhusudhan I ended up in using Framelayout with Edittext(password field), view(which covers Edittext under it) and a nested layout with 4(will be your password length) dotted images on top. Using textwatcher on password field I play with visibility of dotted images i.e if password length is 2 I display two dotted images hiding the rest. Hope I am clear, im tied up with some work currently, will try to write a blog post soon. Keep you posted.

Comment: ya if you could please post some code when done.....

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sriharia.blogspot.com/2014/07/ios-style-password-control-on-android.html) is the link for the blog which explains to achieve above requirement using compound controls. Posting here to save time for others who are looking for this.